# Is the use of CDATA correct to replace <

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

Am I using the CDATA correctly in code below because I am getting no error but getting warnings on start tag `<` starting here...

```
var $tbody = $('#qandatbl_onthefly > tbody');
var $tr = $("<![CDATA[<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'>]]");
var $qid = $("<![CDATA[<td width='5%' class='qid'></td>]]").text(qnum);
var $options = $("<![CDATA[<td><table class='option'><tbody><tr><td class='opt'>1. Option Type:</td></tr></tbody></table></td>]]");
var $video = $("<![CDATA[<td width='17%' class='video'></td>]]");
var $endtr = $("<![CDATA[</tr>]]");
var $questionType = '';
```

Comment: Is there any reason you want to use `CDATA`? From the given code it is not necessary to use it.

Comment: May you post the warning you get?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: If any, the CDATA declaration should only be around the whole content of the `script` tag(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **you dont need to use CDATA** here. It's **used when you get data from XML to recognize that it is the HTML content**

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need the CDATA sections, but the ones you have are incomplete.  The end is missing an additional >:

```
<![CDATA[ ... ]]>

<![CDATA[ <div>...</div> ]]>
```

The trailing angle bracket is missing in the examples you provided.